# Accessing values from json in Pylons

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pylons

In my controller I'm getting a json string (called `c.order_history` which looks like:

```
[
{
    "status": [
        {
            "status": "created",
            "timestamp": "2012-04-06 00:14:10"
        },
        {
            "status": "authed",
            "timestamp": "2012-04-06 00:14:17"
        }
    ],
    "product_info": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "quantity": 1,
            "created": "2012-04-06 00:14:10",
            "image_id": 13341
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "quantity": 1,
            "created": "2012-04-06 00:14:10",
            "image_id": 13323
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "created": "2012-04-06 00:14:10",
            "image_id": 13322
        }
    ],
    "shipping_charge": "0.00",
    "order_number": "0723094747433",
    "shipping_address": {
        "country_code": null,
        "extended_address": "Unit Z",
        "locality": "Las Vagas",
        "company": null,
        "phone": null,
        "postal_code": "31415",
        "full_name": "Boris Karloff",
        "nickname": null,
        "region": "NV",
        "street_address": "123 Random Way"
    },
    "subtotal": "59.00"
}
```

]

I'm passing it through `json.loads(order_history)` to turn it into a dict, and then trying to extract each key so I can then get the subsequent key/values within them like:

`c.product_info = [{'product_info' : product_info} for product_info in c.order_history]`

Which outputs the entire json string, but it's just named `product_info` now. Can someone steer me in the right direction on how I can access say, the `timestamp` value, `product_info[0]['image_id']` and `shipping_address` values, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `c.order_history` will be a list of dictionaries, to just grab the `product_info` key from each of these dictionaries in a list comprehension you would do the following:

```
[{'product_info': order['product_info']} for order in c.order_history]
```

Comment: Thanks. That definitely helped.